# bypass spoof redirection

Tags: php

I have news sports websites in 2 iframes.

```
<div="news">
    <iframe src="news site one"></iframe>
    <iframe src="news site two"></iframe>
</div>
```

The first loads fine but the second doesnt anymore. It just returns a white page with a link to the website directly. Is there a way to spoof this so it thinks I am accessing the site directly. I need to have both websites open side by side.

Comment: That might violate that site's terms of use.  If they are trying to prevent you from displaying their content in an iframe on your site, you might want to find out why.

Comment: Well, if you have firefox you can load up [RefControl](http://www.stardrifter.org/refcontrol/) so it doesn't know it's being loaded from "contoso.com"

Comment: Thats what I thought and I contacted them via email and they told me they were unsure why it was doing that. Said "could be your bowser"

Comment: @Brad -- it's probably worth clarifying that every user of this page would need to install and configure the extension, which may or may not be practical in this situation.

Comment: Is there no php solution to this?

Comment: @Frank: True, good call (though my impression this was a "private" site--i could be wrong).

Comment: @brad -- yeah, that definitely may be the case.  @jack -- no, you can't change the way referrer headers are sent to the target URL in the iframe.  The browser does that on its own; it's essentially beyond PHP's control.  The only way to solve this "with PHP" is to not directly embed the page in the iframe, and instead proxy the request, which has its own challenges.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I would know to spoof it with PHP is to setup a page called `sports2.php` on your site. Then use [`CURL`](http://php.net/curl) to spoof the headers with how you want them and just echo the contents. Then just set your iframe to load `sports2.php`

---

Just a tidbit, just because they say there is "not" protection in place, does not mean that there is not. A lot of times you are not dealing with the programmers / main people at the site and it could be something fairly new implemented, which would be even more likely the contact people do not know about.

Comment: +1. It'd be more complicated than that though -- you'd need to rewrite any relative URLs in the document, and could theoretically run into issues with certain javascript (and applets and anything else with a same-origin policy).  Regardless, this might very well be the solution the OP needs.

Comment: Yea, its a good starting point. What might be a bit better is setting up a proxy host, like squid, and then just routing the site through the proxy host to display.

Comment: Does squid rewrite relative URLs for you?

Comment: It should, if you are displaying the page through a HTTP proxy, everything *should* point to the site. The proxy is more or less a mask to hide your IP / other information (browser etc). But it all depends on how the proxy is setup and what it's intended use is for.